# Probelm showing RGB image using PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

In my code, I am creating an image as a RGB array (224 * 224 * 3).

This is how my image representation looks like:

```
[[[0.44861878 0.64972376 0.95801105],  [0.44861878 0.64972376 0.95801105],  [0.44861878 0.64972376 0.95801105],  ...,  [0.44861878 0.45082873 0.82475138],  [0.44861878 0.45082873 0.83270718],  [0.44861878 0.45082873 0.84066298]],, [[0.44861878 0.64972376 0.95801105],  [0.44861878 0.64972376 0.95801105],  [0.44861878 0.64972376 0.95801105],  ...,  [0.44861878 0.45082873 0.83270718],  [0.44861878 0.45082873 0.83270718],  [0.44861878 0.45082873 0.84066298]],, [[0.44861878 0.65767956 0.95801105],  [0.44861878 0.64972376 0.95801105],  [0.44861878 0.64972376 0.95801105],  ...,  [0.44861878 0.45082873 0.83270718],  [0.44861878 0.45082873 0.83270718],  [0.44861878 0.45082873 0.84066298]],, ...,, [[0.44861878 0.45082873 0.83270718],  [0.44861878 0.45082873 0.82475138],  [0.44861878 0.45082873 0.82475138],  ...,  [0.44861878 0.45082873 0.82475138],  [0.44861878 0.45082873 0.82475138],  [0.44861878 0.45082873 0.82475138]],, [[0.44861878 0.45082873 0.82475138],  [0.44861878 0.45082873 0.82475138],...
```

now, when I use:

```
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

I am getting this image:

[image]

when I use :

```
  image = np.asarray(image * 255, dtype=np.int)
  PIL.Image.fromarray(image, "RGB").show()
```

I am getting :

[image]

Why can't I show the image using PIL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you create a NumPy array of type `np.int` (64-bit signed integer) and PIL expects `np.uint8` (8-bit unsigned integer). Changing `image = np.asarray(image * 255, dtype=np.int)` to `image = np.asarray(image * 255, dtype=np.uint8)` should fix your problem.